# display data received from IoT Hub on View(web page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, iot

I have used  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted as reference to create my ASPNet MVC app

I am using the below code to receive data from IoT Hub

```
private static async Task ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(string partition, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var eventHubReceiver = eventHubClient.GetDefaultConsumerGroup().CreateReceiver(partition, DateTime.UtcNow);
    while (true)
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        EventData eventData = await eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
        if (eventData == null) continue;

        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());

        //Console.WriteLine("Message received. Partition: {0} Data: '{1}'", partition, data);

    }
}
```

By this I see the data gets received in the variable ***string data***
Now I would like to display this data on the View (MVC View i.e. web page) as it gets received from IoT Hub.

### My Query

How should the value in the ***var string data*** be directed to be displayed on View?

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question, but one option would be to use SignalR, you would need something like a WebSocket connection anyway to update the view in real-time.

Comment: The required  data is continuously received from IoTHub;  being inside while loop as per my code shown above.

For next step, please help me how to use SignalR here to sendMessage- send this just_received_data_from_iot_hub - to UI
 Note : data is getting received continuously from IoT hub -- and that its inside the while loop
 
If I say SendMessage -  it will come out the while loop - which means stopped receiving data  from IoT Hub . Please suggest an way to implement this- am new to this so this may be a very basic Question -kindly excuse me for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need some real-time processing infrastructure here.

As @juunas has said, signal-r would be a good option here. Other than that, which would be a large overhead for a simple thing like this if security is a factor, you could either create a web api, or a mvc action that returns a JsonResult, and poll this every x seconds.

UPDATED:

Basically, you cant - You need real time processing for this.

With the while(true) loop, you are blocking the request thread, and it will never return. You could just poll a WebAPI/Json MVC controller that you get the latest message from the IoT Hub message queue.

1. UI polls every X Seconds a WebAPI/MVC Json Action on your app sending the last recieved message id
2. The WebAPI/MVC Json Action get all messages from IoT Hub message queue > last message id
3. Send the new messages back to the client

This will be a simple way to solve your issue, and will be as close to real time as you can get without WebSockets or Signal-R. (BTW, you can host Signal-R in a WebAPI/MVC app, you dont have to have in in a second app)

Comment: Yes I read in different sites we need to use WebSockets or SignalR.
Currently my app is saving the message as a json object and another new web app with jQuery displays that latest json value

It displays fine. But I know that is not an optimal solution -which uses 2 app

The SignalR send one value to the view
My mismatch here is that the value received from IoT Hub is inside while(true) loop 
My mismatch is here.

How to send a value to the UI when I am inside the while(loop) thats continuously receiving data from IoT Hub?

Comment: Basically, you cant You need real time processing for this.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the detailed steps. I shall try this today and let you know  how it goes.